# Not instantly getting out a loop with break

Tags: python

When I run this easy program and want to exit it, I need to type exit 2 times (at line 7).

```
def registration():
def username_registration():
    entering_username = True
    while entering_username:
        print("Type exit to leave the registration.")
        usernam_from_registration = input("Enter username: ")
        if usernam_from_registration == "exit":
            break
        lenght_usernam_from_registration = len(usernam_from_registration)
        if lenght_usernam_from_registration > 15:
            print("too long")
        else:
            return usernam_from_registration
username_registration()
print(username_registration())


registration()
```

Why is this and how can I make it so I only need to write it one time?

Comment: This program has syntax errors. If your question isn't about why this has that, then please construct a [mcve] that can showcase your issue or current code.

Comment: You call `username_registration` twice.  So one `exit` for each call.  That seems right.

Comment: I wish they weren't so hard on new contributors. I started answering but the post got closed. `import sys`, then `sys.exit(0)` for no message, or `sys.exit("message")` to pass a message when it exits. The other answer describes why it's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are calling the `username_registration()` function twice.

```py
username_registration()
print(username_registration())
```

The first time you call it, nothing happens because you are not doing anything with the result.

Comment: Thank you much i did not see my own stupidnes

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! Seeing as it is what you are looking for, could you please mark it as the accepted answer? `n____n`